# Flex div and other div is not coming responsive and height is changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Hi I want to make the following result

[image]

For this i write the following code

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .arri-light{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  }
 .s-img{
  display:none;
 }
.b-img{
display:block;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 991px) {
  
 .s-img{
  display:block;
 }
.b-img{
display:none;
}
}

.but-new {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
.nm-1{
    margin-top: -212px;
    margin-left: 133px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.all-bb{
display: block;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top:22px;

}
.main-img{
  background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/hGFfjpLM/NEW-2.jpg');
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
max-width: 890px;
overflow: hidden;
}


.b-h2 {
    text-align: center !important;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
    color: #383e40 !important;
    font-size: 24px !important;
     font-weight: 400 !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    padding-top: 13px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
   padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.con-righ{
  color:white;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width:90%;
background: #000000ab;
    padding: 36px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.con-left{
  color:white;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width:90%;
background: #000000ab;
    padding: 36px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.new-h4 {
 color: white;
 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 36px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.con-righ p{
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
  padding-right: 23px
}

.but-red{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: white !Important;
    width: max-content;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: unset;
    transition: .3s all;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="all-bb">

<div class="arri-light col-sm-12 col-md-4">

 <img src="https://i.ibb.co/jH5bTZ6/NEW-1.jpg" class="s-img"> 
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/gvDsjVt/NEW-1-BIG.jpg" class="b-img"> 
 <a class="but-red but-new" href="#"> My button</a>

</div>


<div class="main-img col-sm-12 col-md-8">
  <div class="con-righ">
     <h4 class="new-h4">Projects</h4>
     <p class="s-img">Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore </p>
<p class="b-img">Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
     <a class="but-red" href="#"> View  Projects</a>
  </div>

</div></div></div>
```

But i am facing an issue . This 2 divs are not having same height on when the screen size change Please see the following image

[image]

How to solve this. Please help  . In mobile device everything is seems ok . But in small desktop

there is issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `.row` as a `flex` container. It gives you equal height columns.

Like this..

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.arri-light img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/fexubelaja/1/edit?html,css,output)